# x264 enc v4l2 /dev/video2 stream

Tags: gstreamer

I have this working but have been unable to get video from my magwell to intergrate and could use help with the correct pipline. 
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=848,height=480,framerate=25/1 ! x264enc bitrate=700 ! video/x-h264,width=848,height=480,framerate=25/1,stream-format=byte-stream,profile=baseline ! tee name=t\
 t. ! queue ! tcpclientsink host=172.18.0.3 port=8000 \
 t. ! queue ! tcpclientsink host=172.18.0.4 port=8000`

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the receiver side pipeline in the question description. This is required to verify that there are no issues at the receiver side. Based on your current pipeline I have the following suggestions:

1. You don't need set the `caps` again after the element `x264enc`, because the output is anyhow of type `video/x-h264`. What you need is to add `h264parse` after `x264enc`. You need to also add `h264parse`, before passing the data to decoder you are using at the receiver side.
2. The bitrate set for `x264enc` is also very less. The units are in kbits/sec, and for a video this might be very less. It's best to leave this to default setting if you do not have any strict resource constraints. Otherwise try for a higher value.

Also is there any reason why you are using TCP. Using UDP might be a better idea for video, in case video data/packet loss is not an issue.

Comment: I am trying to make it work with this. https://github.com/Dregu/visio which just takes the h264 baseline stream and basically makes it possible to view over a HTML5 canvas.